# pattern repeated in regex php

Tags: php, regex, pcre

> $str='xyzab abab xhababab';

I want to check whether the string contains ab 3 times continuously. Means **ababab**

It does not work :

```
$subject = "xyzab abab xhababab";
$pattern = '/ab{3}/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches2,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
var_dump($matches2);
```

Comment: Is the `ababab` the result you want to get or `xhababab`?

Comment: Yes i want `ababab`. Thanks yours answer match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the `ab` into a grouping construct:

```
(?:ab){3}
^^^  ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uK5pB2/1)

The quantifier is applied to the subpattern that stands to the left of it. So, in `ab{3}` the `{3}` quantifies the `b` symbol and it matches `abbb`. When you group the subpattern sequence and then set a quantifier to the *group*, all the subpattern sequence is quantified then.

Note that `(?:...)` is a [**non-capturing group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) that is used only for grouping, not *capturing* (i.e. no separate memory buffer is provided for the substrings matched with this group).

> If you do not need the group to capture its match, you can optimize this regular expression into `Set(?:Value)?`. The question mark and the colon after the opening parenthesis are the syntax that creates a non-capturing group. The question mark after the opening bracket is unrelated to the question mark at the end of the regex.

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/HG76R7):

```
$subject = "xyzab abab xhababab";
$pattern = '/(?:ab){3}/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches2,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
var_dump($matches2);
```

Comment: `?:`  what  does it do?

Comment: I added more explanations.